# groupby and join in couchbase lite for android

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-lite, couchbase-java-api

I have the following documents for use in Android:

Users:

```
 {"Type" : "User", "UserId" : 920, "InitialCommitment": 2000, "BlockId": 1, "_id" : "User_1_920"},     
 {"Type" : "User", "UserId" : 921, "InitialCommitment": 1800, "BlockId": 1, "_id" : "User_1_921"}
```

where Id is formed in Type_BlockId_UserId

Interests:

```
 {"Type" : "Intr", "UserId" : 920, "IntrId":1, "Value": 11, "BlockId": 1, "_id" : "Intr_1_920_1"},     
 {"Type" : "Intr", "UserId" : 920, "IntrId":2, "Value": 5, "BlockId": 1, "_id" : "Intr_1_920_2"}
```

where id is Intr_BlockId_UserId_IntrId

Basically, I want to get an aggregated data by BlocKId something like this:

```
   BlocKId: 1, totalCommitments:3800, totalInterests: 16
```

I have indexes on Type, UserId, IntrId and BlockId fields. My issue now is my app don't compile because the Sum function does not exist. Secondly, I am doing two queries one to get aggregates for interests and another for commitments. Is there away to join the queries in one go?

```
    val queryTotalCommitment: Query = QueryBuilder.select(
            SelectResult.expression(Function.Sum(Expression.property("InitialCommitment"))),
            SelectResult.property("BlockId"),
            .from(DataSource.database(database))
            .groupBy(
                    Expression.property("BlockId"))


    val queryTotalInterests: Query = QueryBuilder.select(
            SelectResult.expression(Function.Sum(Expression.property("Value"))),
            SelectResult.property("BlockId"),
            .from(DataSource.database(database))
            .groupBy(
                    Expression.property("BlockId"))
```

the error now is Sum does not exist. Am I suppposed to write it? I have already imported Function from couchbaste.lite

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Kotlin. It worked well in Java because public members of non-public super classes are visible from the subclass, which is not the case in Kotlin. [HERE IS MORE](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/groupby-and-join-in-couchbase-lite-for-android/26362/4)

Answer (score 0):

As @Nie points out in his link we are still working on making our API Kotlin friendly.

The specific reason that you the `Sum` function worked in Java but not Kotlin is that in Java, public members of non-public super classes are visible from the subclass. This is not the case in Kotlin. The `Sum` method is declared in a package protected superclass of `Function` (`AbstractFunction`). That means that Kotlin can’t see it.

I expect to fix this problem in a release sometime around the end of this year.

Until then the best solution is a QueryBuilder helper class, written in Java.